# Alerts and Textbox focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found something interesting when testing my program. When an alert pops up you can either close the prompt or refresh the page to get rid of the message. Well on the same page I also had a text box. When I closed the prompt I could click inside the text field, but when I refreshed the page I wasn't able to click in the text field at all.

I'm not looking for a solution for this because I can fix this. What I wanted to know is if any one knew what was going on. Why cant I click in text box after refreshing page while the prompt is opened?

This is not my project, mine is much larger, but shows the same example I was experiencing. This is where I got the code from [Code](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_blur_alert).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").blur(function(){
        alert("This input field has lost its focus.");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

Enter your name: <input type="text">
<p>Write something in the input field, and then click outside the field to lose focus (blur).</p>

</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: I have 2 solutions either reset the focus in the code or have the user click in the web browsers search bar then click back into the text box. I also found while testing the code on this site that I can no longer click in the websites search bar nor could I click in this post to re-edit.

Comment: Have you checked for any JS errors in Developer Tools -> console? Also try different browsers

Comment: I don't really know how to do that. I guess I'm still kind of new.

Comment: Press F12 button. This will show you developer tools. Or google how to see it.

Comment: @SurjitSD console has nothing to do with it :) its not a javascript error or anything else.

Comment: @SurjitSD O lol. Inspect. I didn't know inspecting was the same as developers tools.

Comment: looks more like a chrome bug to me, probably, in an alert dialog "ok" button gets focused automatically, then after refresh, it still stays focused. So to unfocus it (logically) you need to click it. but its hidden, so you press search bar to unfocus button. Just report this bug to https://www.chromium.org/